# Problems how to get the src of the iframe that has the sandbox element using cheerio

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to take the src from the `iframe` but I cannot get the url. Apparently the `iframe` has the `sandbox` element which does not allow me to see the src.

I am using the cloudscraper library that helps me bypass the cloudflare block

Isn't there a way to take the src value?

**Here is the example code**

```js
const cloudscraper = require('cloudscraper');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


const main = async() =>{
  let url = "https://playerhost.net/show/vikings/01-01?watching=R9rz2SEFDoimDILGkMSwQMtxB";
  let res = await cloudscraper(url , {method: 'GET'});
  let $ = cheerio.load(res);
  const iframeURL = $('iframe').attr('src');
  console.log(iframeURL)
};

main();
```

Comment: I imagine the src is loaded by js so you would need something like puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

**solution using puppeteer**

```
const requestIframeWithAttrSandBox = async(url) =>{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const urls = await page.$$eval('iframe', el=> [].map.call(el, d => d.src));
  await browser.close();

  const _url = urls[0];
  return _url
}
```